# Serving static file, not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, file-upload, multer

I have successfully uploaded file inside public folder. I have set static path as 
`app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"))`

The folder structure is as follows.

```
node_modules
public
src
```

Now when I request `http://localhost:5000/public/filename.png` it doesn't display the image. It says, `Cannot GET /public/filename.png`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this 
`const publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, "../public")`

then set static path like so

`app.use(express.static(publicFolder))`

Comment: Oh yes. My index.js file is inside the src folder. That's why ```__dirname``` was serving public folder inside the src folder. But actually, the public folder is outside the src folder. Thank you.